# SHELL SCRIPT: Save egrep results into a Variable

Tags: shell, grep

Hi I am trying to Save my egrep results into a variable and do a foreach. 
However, i keep getting the following error despite with the following type of codes

```
#!/bin/sh    
RESULT1=$(egrep 'Begin|End' $SYNCLOG)
RESULT2=egrep 'Begin|End' $SYNCLOG
RESULT3="egrep 'Begin|End' $SYNCLOG"
```

Errror

```
./test.sh: syntax error at line 24: `RESULT=$' unexpected
```

I am trying to get my egrep results to be saved into the variable.
The egrep will return the following results

```
File 2:Begin - Date :Fri Jan 10 22:44:47 SGT 2014
File 2:End - Date :Fri Jan 10 22:47:06 SGT 2014
File 3:Begin - Date : Tue Jan 11 22:32:54 SGT 2014
File 3:End - Date : Tue Jan 11 22:34:43 SGT 2014
File 4:Begin - Date : Wed Jan 12 22:46:15 SGT 2014
File 4:End - Date : Wed Jan 12 22:48:23 SGT 2014
File 5:Begin - Date : Thu Jan 13 22:30:31 SGT 2014
File 5:End - Date : Thu Jan 13 22:32:51 SGT 2014
```

Comment: Are you sure your first command is written exactly like this? Currently it looks fine. The other two are wrong. In general, use `var=$(command)`.

Comment: Are you really in sh? Check if `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is this shebang of `sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

And use of `$(...)`, which is a BASH syntax.

To fix, you can use this shebang to use bash instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Or else use this command substitution syntax in `/bin/sh`:

```
RESULT1=`egrep 'Begin|End' $SYNCLOG`
```

Comment: i think even if OP uses sh, it should work irrespective of whether OP uses `$(..)` or backticks.

Comment: Are you sure `/bin/sh` supports `$(...)`?

Comment: I really think it does, but I cannot find a proper reference. In fact, in http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/v7/ they just mention ``.

Comment: @fedorqui: I am trying to find a reference or a way to test. On my 2 systems OSX and Linux `/bin/sh` is just a symlink of `/bin/bash` so I am unable to test it at present. I will delete this answer once I figure it out.

Comment: No, no, don't remove the answer! I am also struggling with `sh` being a symlink to `bash` :) I asked for clarification to the OP, let's see what he comments.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have backticks somewhere on line 24. Paste your whole script. Above shell script excerpt i.e.

```
RESULT1=$(egrep 'Begin|End' $SYNCLOG)
```

Should work.